# Parsing big double value C#

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point

Parsing a very big double value is returning wrong value.

For e.g.

```
Double.Parse("987654321098765432109876543210987.99")
```

returns `9.8765432109876547E+32`, which is wrong. How to handle this?

I want to display the above value with comma separated in my web page. Kindly help.

Comment: Your input exceeds `Double` range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Big Integers

`double` has limited precision, so it will only store the first 15-16 digits of your number. For more precision, use `System.Numerics.BigInteger` - it doesn't support
non-integers though, so you must add the decimal points yourself (if you have a
fixed number of decimals).

> **BigInteger Structure**
>
> .NET Framework 4.0+
>
> Represents an arbitrarily large signed integer.

(Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268287%28v=vs.99%29.aspx)

The relevant function:

> **Parse**
>
> Converts the string representation of a number to its BigInteger
>   equivalent.
>
> Namespace:  System.Numerics
>
> Assembly:  System.Numerics (in System.Numerics.dll)
>
> ```
> public static BigInteger Parse(string value)
> ```

(Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268231%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Example:

```
import System.Numerics.BigInteger;
BigInteger.Parse("98765432109876543210987654321098999").ToString(); // note, no dot
```

You would also need to reference the System.Numerics assembly.

## Big fixed-point numbers

If need to have some fixed amount of decimals in the number, you can implement fixed-point arithmetic and I/O yourself. In this example, I'll use two decimal places, but it can
be easily modified.

The key is to not work with the original number, but a multiple of it. For example,
if your number is `X`, it is internally represented as `X * 100`

### Addition and subtraction

Addition and subtraction work without modification. Let's consider numbers X, Y and Z,
and their internal representations:

```
X + Y = Z

X*100 + Y*100 = Z*100
```

Both equations are correct.

### Multiplication and division

Multiplication and division require some arithmetic. Let's modify the previous example
for multiplication:

```
X * Y = Z

(X*100) * (Y*100) = Z*100 <--- WRONG
```

You need to modify the equation somewhat:

```
X * Y = Z

(X*100) * (Y*100) = Z*100*100

Z * 100 = (X*100) * (Y*100) / 100
```

So you need to divide the result by 100 to get the correct internal representation.
With division, you need to multiply both operands by 100 respectively.

### Input and output

If your input always includes two decimal digits, you can just remove the decimal
point to get the internal representation for the number. Free-form input requires
more work.

In output, you'll have to inject the decimal point before the last two digits to
get correct input. Additionally, if the number is less than 0, you may have to
insert zeroes in the front.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) when converting `double` to `string`. By default it uses [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) for big numbers, which is not the best choice for public websites.  I've used `F` in the example, but consider to read **msdn** to find format, that suits your needs best

```
var str = Double.Parse("987654321098765432109876543210987.99").ToString("F");

Console.WriteLine (str);
```

prints

```
987654321098765000000000000000000.00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [custom format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

```
Double.Parse("987654321098765432109876543210987.99").ToString("0,0.00")
```

Output: `"987,654,321,098,765,000,000,000,000,000,000.00"`

You can also download this [utility to test various forma](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=clrsamples&DownloadId=14861)