# How to handle double numbers that exceeds double.Max in C#?

Tags: c#, double

I am working with a method that returns a *large* `double` value (`> 1e308`) and then this value is *multiplied* by a *small* `double` value to obtain a *reasonable number*. My problem is how to handle the `double` values in **C#** that exceed (`1.79E308`) without getting Infinity output?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520441/parsing-big-double-value-c-sharp

Comment: either trim the number down or use Big Integer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using *logarithms* (`Log(1e308) == 709.196...`): instead of

```
 double bigNumber = SomeMethod();          // double.PositiveInfinity
 double smallNumber = SomeOtherMethod();
 double result = bigNumber * smallNumber;  // double.PositiveInfinity
```

Implement

```
 double bigNumber = SomeMethodLog();                  // reasonable value
 double smallNumber = SomeOtherMethodLog();
 // bigNumber will be cancelled out with smallNumber
 double result = Math.Exp(bigNumber + smallNumber);   // reasonable value
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.
1. you can switch to another type that handles such big numbers. But in future you will be able to find another one example where floating point decision breaks your calculations again.
2. Right way. You have to re-design (refactor) your application's calculation flow. Try to find out which part of your code works with big numbers, which part operate small numbers. Work with it separately, and combine results before finish.

Answer (score 0):

First multiply with small number. Then with large number

```
double x = ...; // The number to be multiplied.
double result = x * smallNumber * largeNumber;
```