# How do I print out all the digits in a double variable?

Tags: c#, double

I have this number: 
double number = 131151201344081895336534324866D;

Console.WriteLine(number) writes 1,31151201344082E+29, and Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("#")) only writes 131151201344082000000000000000.

But I want this number to appear on the console window as: 131151201344081895336534324866.

Is there a way I can print out all the digits?

Comment: A `double` has only about 15 significant digits, so it cannot represent the value you gave exactly. `decimal` will give you about 28 significant digits which is better, but still not sufficient four your big number. If your numbers are always integer, you may use [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520441/parsing-big-double-value-c-sharp) (well, the answers are relevant).

Comment: If you weren't limited by significant digits as indicated above, what would you print for `double d = 1.0/3.0`? It's a good idea to familiarize yourself with the limitations of floating-point representations in computer science (in general, not just for this question). https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: use `DoubleConverter.ToExactString(number)` with: https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs

Comment: The closest double to the original input is 131151201344081890417389338624. If you really want to see the original string, save the string, not just its double approximation.

Answer (score 0):

`import java.math.BigDecimal;`

`class BigIntegerFact{`

`public static void main(String args[])`
`{`

        `BigInteger number=new BigDecimal(args[0]);`

            `System.out.println(number);`

`}`

`}`